# Requisição com ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

No meu sistema tenho um modulo de envio de e-mails 
faço o envio através do ajax. 
envio para aproximadamente 300 pessoas na mesma requisição.

O servidor uolhost suporta envio de 150/hora então quando envio 150 dou o comando do php sleep(1hora) e o ajax continua esperando.

gostaria de saber se isso sobrecarrega o servidor se sim, o que fazer para melhor?

Infelizmente a empresa contratou um plano na uolhost que não tem suporte ao cron e nem conexão ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Você tá rodando seu server no limite, então ele consome bastante memória.
Tenta fazer com que o script de envio não dure muito e não use sleep.
Faça uma fila de e-mails a serem enviados, pegue seu script, tire o sleep e coloque a rotina em uma cron Job que executa de hora em hora, na cron Job ele vai consumir menos memória do que uma rotina com loop infinito.

Recomendação, use Mandrill para emails transacionais, é barato e você não vai ter este tipo de problema.

Comment: Infelizmente a empresa contratou um plano na uolhost que não tem suporte ao cron e nem conexão ssh.

Comment: Então use Mandrill( gringo e barato) ou All In mail(brasileiro e caro), envio de e-mails pesam no servidor. Eu digo isso porque trabalhei muito com e-mails transacionais.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não faria os disparos de e-mails usando uma requisição ajax, simplesmente.

Porque você não cria um serviço (cron job) que rode a cada 1 hora e pega todos os emails que ainda não passou pelo processo de envio?

Procura por: php cron job

Comment: Infelizmente a empresa contratou um plano na uolhost que não tem suporte ao cron e nem conexão ssh.

Answer (score 0):

O problema da sua abordagem é que o servidor web (por ex. Apache) ou o gateway (por ex. php-fpm) irá matar esse processo devido ao timeout (tempo limite), que é por padrão configurado em menos de 5 minutos. Você poderia aumentar esse limite, mas isso não é recomendado, pois algum bug no código poderia travar seu servidor e deixar muitos processos rodando indefinidamente.

Você precisa implementar uma fila de tarefas assíncrona, possível através do [Celery-PHP](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php)

O ideal seria algo como o Celery mas como vc não tem acesso ao servidor, aumentar o timeout é a única saída. Recomendo contra deixar o timeout muito alto e estudar alternativas em hospedagem. Dependendo do uso, você consegue fazer isso de graça pelo Heroku por exemplo.

Comment: o problema do timeout eu já resolvi

Comment: Resolveu desabilitando? Timeouts são essenciais num web server, você pode ter problemas maiores http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306605/is-ini-setmax-execution-time-0-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo uma ideia de como fazer o envio automático dos lotes, basta implementar a "paginação" no disparador dos emails...

```js
var enviados = 0, timer;
var emails = 10; // emails por lote
var minutos = 5; // tempo de espera entre lotes

$('#enviar').click(function() {
  $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  
  // ajax que envia o lote de emails
  $.get('enviar.php?enviados=' + enviados + '&emails=' + emails);
  // apenas para teste
  console.log('enviar.php?enviados=' + enviados + '&emails=' + emails);

  // incrementa o contador de envios, isso pode ser colocado no callback success do .get
  enviados += emails;

  // ativa o timer que vai continuar o envio depois do tempo determinado
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#enviar').click();
  }, (60000 * minutos));
});

$('#parar').click(function() {
  $('#enviar').prop("disabled", false);
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
<button id="parar">Parar</button>
```